# "Black marker" effect in the text (sanitization used to hide passwords in code example)

Tags: fonts

I wonder if there is any LaTeX library that allows me to
obtain a sanitization "black marker" effect in order to conceal *omissis* information,
like for example a secret code in an URL or a password in a code listing.

Please have a look at this to get the idea of what I wish to obtain:
[document with *omissis* information](http://newsimg.bbc.co.uk/media/images/46263000/jpg/_46263106_007843745-1.jpg) and [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Aclu-v-ashcroft-redacted.jpg)

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to specify the 'black marker' effect by hand in your code or use some 'keywords'? I would use a wrapper command for a colorbox and a boolean flag which is set before compilation whether portions should be 'blackened' or not. I do not know such a package, but there might be such one anyway.

Comment: @ChristianH. anything that can be useful, any command that may help me. Now that I think about it, a highlighter command set as black may help me achieve this.

Comment: There is still one caveat: Do you want to use that document to be printed or just as a `.pdf` file -- I am not sure, whether 'secret parts' can be nevertheless identified in the `pdf` code.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There also is the Steven B. Se­gletes's [`censor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/censor) package ([documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/censor/censor.pdf)).

You can use `\censor{blurg}` to censor short pieces of text.

Long paragraphs can be blacked out with `\blackout{foo\par bar}`.

Censoring can be turned off via `\StopCensoring`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{censor}

\begin{document}
When shall we \censor{three meet again}, in thunder, lightning or in rain?

Hi \blackout{Hello

Goodbye} Bye

\StopCensoring
When shall we \censor{three meet again}, in thunder, lightning or in rain?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have but one thing to say about your solution: ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `:-)`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Great package.  Thanks! Any chance you could add the ability to censor citations?  If that's too much trouble what about just an \ifcensor command to the package so I don't have to redefine \StopCensor if I want to bootstrap some more complicated logic?

Comment: @PeterGerdes As to the latter point, while an `\ifcensor` may be more elegant than the current state, I'm not sure how typing `\StopCensor` in the preamble is any more onerous than typing `\censorfalse`.  As to the question about citations, I know that citations come in many different flavors and I fear each one would require its own logic, if it were even possible.  Can you be more specific about what you had in mind (including desired syntax), since my own citation experience is limited to BibTeX?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Using StopCensor is fine.  I wasn't suggesting changing that.  Rather, since I figured it would be hard to handle citation systems generally, I thought it would be nice if \StopCensor set if a conditional (e.g. newif or related) that I could use to execute one command if censoring is active and another if it is inactive.  Basically, I want to be able to check if \StopCensor was set but right now it looks kinda messy to do that (either override it or check funky named macro equality).  But maybe I'm just not seeing a good way to do that.

Comment: @PeterGerdes I see.  Perhaps the package could define `\newif\ifcensor` with the default being `\censortrue` while `\StopCensoring` could set `\censorfalse`and `\RestartCensoring` could set `\censortrue`.  Would that seem to provide what you need?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, that was exactly what I was hoping you'd add.

Comment: @PeterGerdes I have submitted censor v4.3 to CTAN with these changes.  Should propagate in the coming days.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Depending on whether you want to mark only short strings of text you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newif\ifmarksecrets % declare new switch
\marksecretstrue %comment or use \marksecretsfalse to display normal text
\newcommand{\secret}[1]{
   \ifmarksecrets % Show black rule
      \rule{\widthof{#1}}{\heightof{#1}}
   \else % Just display text
      #1
   \fi   
   }

\begin{document}
Foo foo foo \secret{VERY SECRET BAR} foo foo foo.
\end{document}
```

For larger boxes, TikZ can be used to draw anything anywhere on the page, but I'm in a bit of a hurry so I can't provide an example now.

Comment: One should point out that this solution cannot line break in the middle of the censor.