# How to centre text?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, paragraphs

I want to write some text in the centre like the following?

[image]

**EDIT:**
Sorry the picture seems caused confusion. I retracted some text for privacy. What I want is just how to center the text in the same way in the picture. To make the alignments like in the picture.
But I do not want to make the highlight or retraction. Just the centering.

Comment: You seem to want the `quote` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
{\textbf{\Longstack[l]{
  Question 1: Can we archive the blacked out text\\
  so that it can be left aligned?\\\\
  Question 2: Can we archive the blacked out text\\
  so that it can also be centered?
}}}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `hl` command (in `soul` package) to highlight text. For your purpose, just set the highlight color is black `\sethlcolor{black}`. The default highlight color is yellow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\sethlcolor{black}
%\sethlcolor{green}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
\noindent\bfseries Question 1: Can we archive \hl{text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text } ?\\

\noindent\bfseries Question 2: Can we archive \hl{text texttext text text text text text text text text text } ?
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that text written with black highlighting can still be selected in a pdf viewer to make it visible, or extracted with tools like `pdftotext`. To prevent this you can use for example the `censor` package, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165139/black-marker-effect-in-the-text-sanitization-used-to-hide-passwords-in-code-e/165145. However, the goal of the OP does not seem to be to make the text unreadable, but only to center the block (what your answer also provides).